# Render the contents of a div at 25% of the actual size

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ios-simulator

Currently, I am working on a simple iOS simulator in JavaScript so users can see how content they have created looks on an iPhone and iPad. To do this, I am using AJAX to load the content/page into the simulator. The only problem is that the simulator isn't life sized. They are perfectly to scale though, so they will fit in a browser.

What I want to know is: is there a way to make the contents of a div render at 50% or 25% of the scripted CSS size? Otherwise, the content will show at pixel-to-pixel size, instead of scaled down.

Comment: kinda, except the simulator doesn't work for me. Also, I'm trying to make my own solution, so users don't have to go to an outside website. And an outside site wouldn't work, as they are previewing stuff before it goes live on the website, so it wouldn't have a url they could test.

Comment: also, that site uses 1-to-1 pixels, which I don't want to do, I want to shrink the pixels to fit in a smaller simulator.

Comment: Have you looked into CSS transforms? eg. body{transform:scale(0.25)}

Comment: a ha! I didn't even think about transforms. I suppose I don't use them enough to have something like that just come to me. You should post that as an answer so I can give you points or whatever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transform property. something like
    transform:scale(0.50, 0.50)
obviously you should replace the two arguments respectively for other scales.
refer to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_scale to get the hang of it.

Comment: Yeah, got it from willem. Thanks though.

Comment: I should get used to looking at comments, sometimes they contain the right answer.

Comment: actually, people should post the correct answer... as an answer! not in the comments. lol